# Some users need administrative privileges to run my program

Tags: c#, .net, privilege, administrative

I read from "Hkey_Current_User" and create file in "AppData" folder.

While many users run my program without problems, some are required to activate windows "Administrator" account and install software before they are able to run my program. Even if they already have administrative privileges.

What should i do?

Comment: It is a pretty nasty workaround for UAC restrictions.   Talk to the IT staff at the site of one of those machines, high odds they did something about it.

Comment: "install software"? What software? .NET runtime? You're not giving us a lot of information to go on :)

Comment: By software i meant  my application . Users should activate windows "Administrator" account and install my application there to be able to run it although their account has administrative privilege.